# Excel Pivot values as column labels

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a Dependent drop-down list in excel using data from a pivot table.
The source data looks like this:

```
+--------+---------+
|  Name  | Country |
+--------+---------+
| John   | USA     |
| Albery | USA     |
| Mary   | Canada  |
| Bob    | Canada  |
| Alice  | Mexico  |
+--------+---------+
```

Using Pivot I am able to fetch the data dynamical in a similar setup. However, in order to create a dependent drop-down lists for an Entire Column like like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg65qPV9fBc&ab_channel=ChesterTugwell) tutorial. I need the pivot to dynamically display data like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Canada | Mexico |  USA   |
+--------+--------+--------+
| Bob    | Alice  | Albery |
| Mary   |        | John   |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

**Is this even possible using pivot, or is there any other way to achieve this?**

*Attached [Excel file](https://file.io/dQR3ErmBLscx)*

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel for Office 365 (or Excel 2021) with the `FILTER` function, you can use the following:

*Note that I used a table with structured references for the data source. This has advantages in editing the table in the future*

For "pivot" header:
`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(Table1[Country])))`

For the columns: 
`F2: =FILTER(Table1[[Name]:[Name]],Table1[[Country]:[Country]]=F$1)`

and fill across. The results in Columns `F:H` will SPILL down.

[image]

If you don't have those functions, you can pivot text using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365